# Pages- IPHONE apps

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, pages

I’ve actually locked some of my important information in a documents in Pages. Been excessing those information through ‘finger print’ technology in iPhone 6s.

Now having upgraded my iphone to X,  I’m unable to access pages as it doesn’t offer ‘finger print’ ability and I’ve forgotten the password.

How can I get access to my password or change it to get access to the information perhaps by an alternate way in which I could access pages and it’s information in my iPhone X?

Comment: Your iPhone X has Face ID which should work all places where the fingerprint did. I've left that out of the answer, but please ping me in comments to my answer if you edit your post with more details how you've locked things.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to log into https://www.icloud.com/#pages from any modern browser on a computer and save out the files since by default pages will store files in iCloud if you sign in once.

If they aren't there, your next easiest step would be to restore that iPhone backup to any device - even one you rent or borrow - iPad / iPhone / iPod Touch and export out the files.

Worst case is you need to get your phone synced or repaired without wiping the data. That will be hard in almost all cases. Even the FBI has problems getting into data, but you might have luck getting Apple to reset your password if you have it set up and know how to verify your identity.

Try http://iforgot.apple.com to see about resetting your password. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you will try this out if non other ways or means are available